# Load Recyclerview data behind the loading view

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, android-recyclerview, adapter

i'm working with recyclerview. 
I have "loadingView" who is a full-screen view with loading indicator.
I have fullscreen recyclerview with datas.

When i get recyclerview data - i start hide animation (fade) for loadingView. 
 
Then recyclerview starts onBindViewHolder and because of big data, my animation is interrupt.

**Is there any posibility to force onBindViewHolder before animation start?** Normally, onBindViewHolder is started only when recyclerview is visible :(

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

When receive data , you can start the animation and use handler to post delay notifyDataSetChanged after 0.5 or 1 second.

Comment: I want to make NotifyDataSetChanged() -> then start animation :(